# Why do these two codes give the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**CODE 1:**

```
>>> data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> for i, x in enumerate(data, 1):
        print(i, x)
```

**CODE 2**:

```
>>> data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> for i, x in enumerate(data, 1):
        print(i, x)
        i += 1
```

**RESULT (for both):**

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

Why does incrementing in the second code have no effect on the result?

Comment: The value of `i` is automatically updated at each iteration. It does not matter how you change it, the changes are overwritten, anyway.

Comment: Python `for` loops are for-each loops, not init-test-increment loops. Screwing with the loop variable doesn't affect the next element in a for-each loop.

Comment: @DYZ I understand, but what mechanism is used to remember the previous state of i? Does this have anything to do with the concept of the scoping variable in python?

Comment: provide expected output.

Comment: The entire point is that ``i`` *is not* remembered between iterations. ``enumerate`` has its own, internal counter that is separate from ``i``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i` value you get from the iteration is the **output** of the `enumerate` function, not an input to it.

Modifying it does not affect the course of the enumeration, and the `for...in` loop will continually overwrite the variable with whatever `enumerate` produces, regardless of what you set it to within the loop body.

Unlike Java and C, loops in python iterate over [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). They don't depend on counters.

Answer (score 1):

Some insight can be found by taking a look at the byte code that CPython produces in your second example:

```
>>> from dis import dis                                                                                           
>>> def with_increment(): 
        for i, x in enumerate(data, 1): 
            print(i, x) 
            i += 1                                                                                                              
>>> dis(with_increment)                                                                                           
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 42)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (enumerate)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (data)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                26 (to 40)
             14 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  3          20 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             28 POP_TOP

  4          30 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             32 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             34 INPLACE_ADD
             36 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   40 POP_BLOCK
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

The part we're interested in is bytes 12-38, which correspond to the body of the loop. Each iteration starts by performing the following actions in sequence:

- `UNPACK_SEQUENCE 2` - The components of the tuple produced by `enumerate` are pushed onto the stack.
- `STORE_FAST 0` - The value on the top of the stack is stored in the first local variable (`i`).
- `STORE_FAST 1` - The value on the top of the stack is stored in the second local variable (`x`).

The key thing to note here is that we never look at the current value of `i`---each iteration blindly overwrites it with whatever was produced by the iterator. Whatever object used to be in `i` during the previous iteration is completely forgotten.